# Datagridview image column based on column text

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I have datagridview with some columns within it. One of the column presents some digits. I would like based on digits let's say there could be either 1, 2 or 3 create additional column wihcih i could put pictures based on that digits. What i tried so far is not workiing as i expected. Can you helop me out what i am doing wrong?:

this is my digit column:

```
dgvTransport.Columns(8).Visible = True
```

My additional image column:

```
  Dim img As DataGridViewImageColumn = New DataGridViewImageColumn()
            img.HeaderText = "Status2"
            img.Name = "Status2"
            img.DisplayIndex = 16
            dgvTransport.Columns.Add(img)
```

and i make this one for grid:

```
 Private Sub dgvTransport_CellFormatting(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs) Handles dgvTransport.CellFormatting


       Dim sHeader As String = dgvTransport.Columns(e.ColumnIndex).Name

    If sHeader = "Status2" Then
        Dim LINK = dgvTransport.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(8).Value

        If LINK.ToString.Contains("1") Then
            Dim Img As New DataGridViewImageCell
            Img.Value = Image.FromFile("C:\Users\Robert\Desktop\1.png")
            dgvTransport.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(16).Value = Img.Value
        End If
        If LINK.ToString.Contains("2") Then
            Dim Img As New DataGridViewImageCell
            Img.Value = Image.FromFile("C:\Users\Robert\Desktop\2.jpg")
            dgvTransport.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(16).Value = Img.Value
        End If
        If LINK.ToString.Contains("3") Then
            Dim Img As New DataGridViewImageCell
            Img.Value = Image.FromFile("C:\Users\Robert\Desktop\3.png")
            dgvTransport.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(16).Value = Img.Value
        End If
    End If
End Sub
        End If
```

this is the error which occurs on line:

```
 Img.Value = Image.FromFile("C:\Users\Robert\Desktop\3.png")
```

error information:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
```

i even tried to fill in image in separate method instead of cellformating event like that but i see only empty x's in my column's rows..:

```
 Private Sub PlaceImages()

   For Each row As DataGridViewRow In dgvTransport.Rows
        If Not row.IsNewRow Then
            Dim Img As New DataGridViewImageCell
            Img.Value = Image.FromFile("C:\Users\Robert\Desktop\1.png")
                         dgvTransport.Rows(row.Index).Cells(16) = Img
        End If
    Next

end Sub
```

i also tried this way but also see only red x:

```
For i As Integer = 0 To dgvTransport.Rows.Count - 1
    Dim sHeader As String = dgvTransport.Columns(16).Name

    If sHeader = "Status2" Then
        Dim LINK = dgvTransport.Rows(i).Cells(8).Value

        If LINK.ToString.Contains("1") Then
            Dim Img As New DataGridViewImageCell
            Img.Value = My.Resources._1.GetHbitmap
            dgvTransport.Rows(i).Cells(16).Value = Img
        End If
        If LINK.ToString.Contains("2") Then
            Dim Img As New DataGridViewImageCell
            Img.Value = My.Resources._2.GetHbitmap
            dgvTransport.Rows(i).Cells(16).Value = Img
        End If
        If LINK.ToString.Contains("3") Then
            Dim Img As New DataGridViewImageCell
            Img.Value = My.Resources._3.GetHbitmap
            dgvTransport.Rows(i).Cells(16).Value = Img
        End If
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Please can you edit in the full error (including stack trace)?

Comment: What size is that image?

Comment: Very small 40x40. Look my main post again i placed it in separated method - now i can see grid loaded but empty pictures images appeared (x)

Comment: anyone have idea whats wrong?

Comment: as you see i tried many ways and still got only red images...

Comment: what is `My.Resources._1`? you may most probably need `Img.Value = My.Resources._1`

Comment: my image... I also check your way not working.. ;/ see only red empty images in grid

Comment: maybe there is something wrong when i am adding this new column ... when i first inititate grid population and says what columns has to be visible/not visible... when first time populate is called my new image column appear on last but when i select change my combobox which will fire again ppulation of grid and then aligment again... this last image column is going to be placed 1 place to left within columns, and if will go again combox selection change , grid refres , aligment then again next place to left. What could be wrong here?